# Can S3 object metadata be used facets in Amazon kendra?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kendra

I wanted to know whether the s3 object meta data can be used as a facet in Amazon Kendra? As kendra generallhy index the whole document before creating the meta data but if we define meta data directly in an s3 object can it be used directly as a facet in kendra to filter search result? If it cannot be done directly do we need coding to get the meta data from the s3 object and then save it and then re index it and reconcile it before it can be used as a facet in kendra?

Any assistance would be helpful.

I am just expecting an approach on how do we get the s3 object meta data as a facet in kendra.